# Redirect "ONLY" the domain's root URL to a subdirectory

Tags: redirect

I am having troubles while redirecting my domain to a subfolder. For example I want to redirect my domain: `mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/test` but only in this subfolder. When I create a new subfolder in the root for example `mydomain.com/test2` it redirects me to `mydomain.com/test`. Is there any rule that redirects only the main URL to the subfolder?

What i have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ test/index.php [L]
```